# Iframe tag not supperted in mozilla firefox?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox, ionic-framework

```
 <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FTPxORAlT0Y">hai</iframe>

</div>
```

This is my code!
Its working well on Chrome but is not loading in Mozilla.
is there any other method of using iframe on mozilla?

Comment: Can you show us what is the output of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iframe certainly is supported with mozilla browser.

Take a look [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=iframe)

Besides, I have also tried your code in mozilla and it works.

I do not know why fail to you.